# accuracy of alphabet drawn on top of movie clip in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, canvas, actionscript

I want to create a simple courseware to teach alphabet to preschool student. 
I have created this code.

```
var Drawing:Number=1;
var LineSize:Number=5;
var DrawColor:Number=0x000000;

var Canvas_sp:Sprite=new Sprite();
this.addChild (Canvas_sp);
Canvas_sp.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,0);
Canvas_sp.graphics.drawRect (18.15,74.45,349.60,291.65);

var Drawing_sh:Shape=new Shape();
this.addChild (Drawing_sh);
Canvas_sp.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,MouseUp);
Canvas_sp.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,MouseDown);
Canvas_sp.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,MouseMove);

function MouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
Drawing=0;
}

function MouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
var CanX:Number=Drawing_sh.mouseX;
var CanY:Number=Drawing_sh.mouseY;

Drawing = 1;
Drawing_sh.graphics.lineStyle(LineSize,DrawColor);
Drawing_sh.graphics.moveTo(CanX,CanY);
}

function MouseMove (e:MouseEvent):void
{
var CanX:Number=Drawing_sh.mouseX;
var CanY:Number=Drawing_sh.mouseY;
if (Drawing==1)
{
    Drawing_sh.graphics.lineTo(CanX,CanY);
}

}
```

i have created several doted line to form an alphabet on the stage which converted all of them to separated movie clips. So how can i trace if user drawn alphabet on top of the movie clip so I can give score for marking for each of the movie clip that has been touch by the line drawn.

Another one is I created a multiple frame which an alphabet for one frame. when user click next button to move to the next frame, i put a code to clear all graphics in the canvas. but it gave some error. heres a code and the error.

```
stop();
/*next button*/
function gonextB53(event:MouseEvent):void
{
Drawing_sh.graphics.clear();
gotoAndStop(2);
}Object(this).nextB53.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, gonextB53);
```

the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at PSM_activities_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[PSM_activities_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:124]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at PSM_activities_fla::MainTimeline/gonextB53()[PSM_activities_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:135]
```

Comment: You might want to correct some grammatical issues, your question is quite confusing.

Comment: `So how can i trace if user drawn alphabet on top of the movie clip` Look into using the methods `hitTest`.. you can try usng collision detection to see if drawn line collides with alphabet movieclips (in other words, they touched or drew over them)..